# How to extract whatsapp messages.db message backup?

Tags: whatsapp

Whatsapp creates snapshots of its data backups on the phone.  I can access this `messages.db` file, but is there a way to extract the data from it?
It's not a standard compression it seems.

Comment: AFAIK, those are encrypted because of security reasons.

Comment: I have contacted other providers of whatsapp extractors for other platforms, e.g. iPhone: jihosoft.com, fireebok.com, reincubate.com, imactools.com and asked them if their product can open a Windows Phone whatsapp backup file too.

Answer (score 2):

I found this article that details how to do it, but only on Windows Phone 7 and it doesn't apply anymore because in the article their messages.db file just opens up without a problem in a sqllite viewer:

http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/windows-phone-digital-forensics-2/

It requires an app called [Windows Phone Device Manager TouchXperience](http://www.touchxperience.com/windows-phone-device-manager/) - all the details are in the article.

The problem is, Windows Phone 7 devices can't be developer unlocked/registered anymore.

---

It is also said that you can also use Windows Phone Power Tools - http://wptools.codeplex.com/

Comment: This doesn't seem to apply to all versions of Windows Phone.

Comment: I am pretty desperate about getting news on this topic... I've extractec my messages.db file... What should I do now to read it?

Answer (score 1):

On most of smart-devices, .db files are generally SQLite database, it will start with "SQLite format 3" if you open your .db with any hexadecimal editor at offset 0 you should find the header string: "SQLite format 3\000", you can use Db Browser for SQLite, you can grab it from [here](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. The snapchat files are encypted

Comment: @DavidPostill My bad sorry I had my half attention.

Comment: @DavidPostill the question is not about Snapchat but WhatsApp. I am using the Android app and the messages are stored in the file msgstore.db which is not encrypted and can be read with the Linux command sqlite3 and the SQL query "select * from messages;". It is probably similar with Windows Phone.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract decrypted `messages.db` after unlocking the phone. In here you can find win10 instructions https://www.winwazzapmigrator.com/faq/windows-how-extract-messagesdb

Comment: Please post the full solution in your answer instead of just a link to an external site. Link-only answers [may be deleted](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: I linked a page because the whole process is pretty complex  to describe and I keep detailing step by step, since it's a work in progress.

Comment: When you've finished, you should still at least summarise the solution in your answer, in case the link becomes unavailable. See also our Help Center article on [how to write a good answer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What's the format of the messages.db after this extraction process? Is it then still encrypted with the WhatsApp encryption that only the original app is good at opening?

Comment: @DaviddCeFreitas after the procedure it's standard SQLite